# AngularDart: How to use two ng-repeat expressions with one tag?

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

I need to create a grouped table, similar to:

```
    Customer            Site
    ------------------------------
    Customer 1          Site 1.1
                        Site 1.2
                        Site 1.3
    Customer 2          Site 2.1
                        Site 2.2
```

To do so in HTML I would need to attach two ng-repeats to a single tr element:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers" ng-repeat="site in customer.sites">
        <td> {{ customer.name }}</td>
        <td> {{ site.name }}</td>
    </tr>
```

This exact syntax doesn't work. Div and Span tags inside the Tbody are not allowed. I would prefer not to pre-format data 
in the controller. I just need a way to use two ng-repeats with a single TR tag. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a table model and a single ng-repeat.

Take the `customers` list and convert it into something that represents the rows of your table:

```
get customerAndSiteNames () {
   // naive approach. maybe use List.expand
   var result = [];
   customers.foreach((customer) {
       result.add({
         'customer': customer.name
         'site' : customer.sites[0].name
       });
       customer.sites.sublist(1).forEach((site){
         result.add({
           'site' : site.name
       }
   }
   return result;
}
```

```
<tr ng-repeat="customerSite in customerAndSiteNames">
    <td> {{ customerSite.customer }}</td>
    <td> {{ customerSite.site }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I wish there was a way to do it in the template. However, this solves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: It will slow down the data population if your data is even slightly bigger. Recommended only for the data count <= 10

Answer (score 2):

So far I found one solution. Apparently tbody tag could be repeated.

So I can do something like:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="customer in customers">
    <tr ng-repeat="site in customer.sites">
        <td> {{ customer.name }}</td>
        <td> {{ site.name }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

However, the initial question still stands.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `rowspan`:

```
<table>
      <tbody ng-repeat="customer in customers">
        <tr ng-repeat="site in customer.sites">
          <td rowspan="{{customer.sites.length}}" ng-if="$index==0">{{customer.name}}</td>
          <td>{{site.name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

[Here is a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hvOKJxxItwmTsn4PaP0j?p=preview)

The `ng-if` part means that only add the `tr` DOM for the first row. It looks like it can be improved, but it gets the job done at least.

Comment: Thanks! This is useful for suppressing the repeated customer names.

Comment: @MikhailTurilin Does this solves your problem? Please kindly mark this as the correct answer if it does :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does not solve the problem "How to use two ng-repeat expressions with one tag?" If develops my workaround solution adding specific tags of table formatting, which wasn't the questions I asked about. Anyways thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [ng-repeat-start](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to accomplish this:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="customer in customers"> 
   <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="site in customer.sites">
      <td> {{ customer.name }}</td>
      <td> {{ site.name }}</td>
   </tr>
</tr>
```